# hdfs dfs -ls with wildcard on path and file name

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to get all files under certain root directories with patterns in sub directories and file name.

i.e.

```
below are hdfs path and files I'd like to filter from current partition/hdfs directories

/parent/2020-03-15/1/sales_28394.txt
/parent/2020-05-20/3/sales_38750.txt
/parent/2020-06-30/5/sales_97412.txt
```

so I'd like to list all above files among others using following command (sort of)

```
hdfs dfs -ls /parent/*/sales_*.txt
```

but I couldn't find a viable solution. It's a bit challenging as pattern need to be considered from both path and file name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `find` command:

```
hdfs dfs -find /parent -name "sales_*.txt"
```

Note that `find` is only available in v2.7+. You can read more about it [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#find)

If you're using an older version you could pipe the output into grep:

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R -C /parent | grep "sales_.*\.txt$"
```

`-R` for recursive, `-C` for file names only.

Comment: thanks and how to add wild card in the path besides file name

Comment: You can use wildcards in the path the same way you do with unix, you just need to use double quotes e.g. ```hdfs dfs -ls -R -C "/parent/*" | grep "sales_.*\.txt$"```.